# Can't use MediaElementAudioSource due to CORS access restrictions

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the Audio API, and I can't play audio.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m305au2d/) is a reproduction of the issue. If you open the js console, after triggering play/pause on the video, you'll see a message saying `VM374:1MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for https://s3.amazonaws.com/mettavr/dev/VfE_html5.mp4` and no audio is played. (it's not an error, but just an info log)

I've found a few SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308679/mediaelementaudiosource-outputs-zeros-due-to-cors-access-restrictions-local-mp3) one or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083704/mediaelementaudiosource-outputs-zeroes-due-to-cors-access-restrictions) one. It sounds that the flag `crossorigin` should be set to `anonymous` and that the server permissions should allow cross origin.

I'm serving the file from a S3 bucket that seems to have opened enough permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Range</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Still, I can't play my audio

======

Edit 1: clarify when the info message appears

Comment: i don't get any error on that link in chrome fwiw...

Comment: And do you get sound? I don't get any sound, and after sometime I get an info message in the console (not an error) saying `MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for ...`

Comment: no sound, but no error message either.

Comment: Weird. It's also not happening very consistently for me. I've to click on play/pause a couple of times to see it

Comment: @Guig Are you trying to play sound from `.mp4` video loaded at `src` of  `<video>` element at `<audio>` element?

Comment: yes it's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to stream your audio out to a peer using [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC) for example, you don't need to use `AudioContext.createMediaStreamDestination()`.

This function will create a `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` associated to a `WebRTC MediaStream` representing an audio stream which may be stored in a file or sent to another computer / browser. One common usage is to sent it to a remote peer using the RTCPeerConnection `addStream()` method.

In your case, if you just want to output the sound so it plays your audio, you can use the `destination` property of your `AudioContext`. It often represents an actual audio-rendering device such as your device's speakers.

```
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById('video'));

var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

You can check the result on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hufd6fbk/2/).

Comment: Ah thanks! Any idea about the CORS restrictions for streaming audio?

Answer (score 2):

You can request the resource as an `ArrayBuffer` or a `Blob` using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, and set both the `<video>` and `AudioContext` at the time, or load `AudioContext` from `<video>` `src`.

Use `.decodeAudioData` for `ArrayBuffer` or use `URL.createObjectURL` with `Blob` as parameter. This is a workaround for the issue described at [Why aren't Safari or Firefox able to process audio data from MediaElementSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958158/why-arent-safari-or-firefox-able-to-process-audio-data-from-mediaelementsource)? See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202652/). See also [Getting Started with Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).

At approach below loaded both `<video>` and `AudioContext` using `Blob`, `FileReader()` to convert `Blob` to `ArrayBuffer`. Note also `source.start(0)` to start audio context playback.

Included `<input type="range">` element to adjust `gainNode` `value` once `AudioContext` loaded.

`TODO`, progress handler and display while video and audio are loading.

```
<label>adjust audio gain<br>
<input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="2.5" step=".5" disabled /></label>
<video src="" id="video" controls="true" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

```
var src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mettavr/dev/VfE_html5.mp4";
fetch(src)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(e.target.result, (buffer) => {
      console.log(buffer); // `AudioBuffer`
        // creates a sound source
      var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;
      gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
      gainNode.gain.value = 2.5;
      // tell the source which sound to play
      source.connect(gainNode);
      // connect the gainNode to the context's destination
      // (the speakers)
      gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      source.start(0);
      console.log(source, audioCtx);
      range.removeAttribute("disabled")
    });
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m305au2d/2/

Comment: @Guig Version using `ArrayBuffer` without `Blob` https://jsfiddle.net/m305au2d/5/